# Reflection in Objective-C (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, reflection

I want to populate [MyClass class] from a JSON string.

I use json-framework to get the NSDictionary, and it's dead easy to instantiate and setValue: forKey:... on my data object.

But for more complex data objects with classes as members of MyClass,

ie:

```
MyOtherClass *classNoTwo
```

I tried with

```
Class test = object_getClass(myClass.classNoTwo);
id foo = [[test alloc] init];
```

But foo is nil/null. The only way I found to get around it is to in my init method of MyClass is to alloc memory for it, and later replace it.

I would also like to know how to get rid of the myClass.classNoTo reference, as I am not supposed to know all the properties in my general parser.

Please don't just tell me to read the documentation, because I've done that, and I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Please don't just tell me to...", new visitors to any forum should tread a little more gingerly than that.

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `class_getProperty()` to access a property of a particular name and then `property_getAttributes()` on the property returned by the first function. This will return a string that encodes the property's attributes, including the type. The format of the string is explained in [Property Type Strings](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101-SW6) in the documentation.

Finally, when you have derived the type of the property, use `NSClassFromString()` to instantiate an object.

Also see the docs for the two functions mentioned for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a very simple dependency injection container called [Factory](http://github.com/zoul/Factory/). I do not get your question entirely, but the problems we solve look similar. Take a look at my sources, they are very simple and should get you started. You might be interested especially in the [ClassAnalyzer](http://github.com/zoul/Factory/blob/master/Source/ClassAnalyzer.m) class. It’s just a hack, but you should be able to get what you want from there.